# Non-normal Subgroup of Quaternion Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, quaternions

I needed to show that the $Q_8\times Q_8$ contains a non-normal subgroup where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group.

My example was the subgroup $\{(1,1), (i,k), (-i,-k)\}$.

I got the question wrong because, according to Lagrange's theorem, my subgroup cannot actually be a group because its order does not divide the order of $Q_8 \times Q_8$.

This makes sense; however, I do not understand why this set fails to be a group explicitly. It seems to me that it is closed and associative. It obviously has the identity and the other 2 elements are inverses of each other.

If this set is not a group it should fail one of these criteria, unless there is something I am not understanding.

Would anyone be able to shed some light on why my set fails to be a group explicitly other than Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: $(i,k)^2$ is what, exactly?

Comment: Oh, that is what I was missing. I didn't account for the elements that acted on themselves. $(i,k)^2 = (-1, -1)$ which means my set is not closed. Thank you.

Comment: Review the axioms for a subgroup. For *every* two elements, the product and the inverse has to be again in the set.

Comment: Use `$\times$` for $\times$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ must be closed under *every product in $H$, including powers of elements*. Since

$$(i,k)^2=(i^2,k^2)=(-1,-1)$$

is not in your example, it cannot be a subgroup.